# Oracle 12519 : Issues while running integration test suite

Tags: oracle, ora-12519

I have a test suite which contains about 4000 tests in it. We use Oracle as our database .
When i run the test suite , some tests run fine and after some time i get **ORA-12519 TNS:no appropriate service handler found**

When i run the tester in isolation , it works correctly , so guess the issue is with the connection to the oracle database located on my machine

I followed couple of posts online and did Run the command “alter system set processes=150 scope=spfile;” in the SQL*Plus   but that did not help too

Did some one experience this issue before and what do i need to do to get if fixed?

I would be awesome if some one could explain the cause and the required action

Thanks

Comment: The `alter system ... scope=spfile` command won't have any effect until the database is bounced. Sounds like maybe you're running too many tests in parallel, or aren't closing connections as tests complete.

Comment: yea i bounced my database. Also these testers are run comfortably by my team members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql*Plus as system and use this

alter system set processes=600 scope=spfile; (instead of 150 , i set it to 600)

Make sure that you restart your database.

This is answered here

[What can cause intermittent ORA-12519 (TNS: no appropriate handler found) errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205160/what-can-cause-intermittent-ora-12519-tns-no-appropriate-handler-found-errors)

Thanks

Comment: this will delay/mask the issue, not solve the underlying problem. Bad in case of a test of course, as on a production machine the processes parameter will be the default, 150 (for regular Oracle, lower for XE), most likely. The underlying problem is that the application (here through the test suite) is attempting to open too many simultaneous connections.