# junit + spring - Listener refused the connection with the following error

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, junit

i am running junit tests with spring application context.
Context creation:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("setUp start");
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/appContext.xml", "/databaseContext.xml");
    bean1 = (Bean1) ctx.getBean("bean1");
    bean2 = (Bean2) ctx.getBean("bean2");       
    System.out.println("setUp end");
}
```

Problem is I am getting strange error when I testing db functionality. It is working fine, connection to DB is established, but if test run longer (> 1 minute) I got strange error. Looks like connection/session is closed. I don't understand why and what exactly is happening.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at         org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodI

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
... 46 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
CRS123:1521:WEBTEST1

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:420)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 51 more
```

Eclipse
Java 6
Spring 3.1
Hibernate 3.6.1
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition

DBContext.xml:

```
<beans>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:CRS123:1521:WEBTEST1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>batman</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>batman</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            .....
            .....
            ....
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">
                auto
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>    
</beans>
```

Could please help, what is the problem here? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not substituting the database host, port, instance names -

eg

url = jdbc:oracle:thin:host:port:instance

Id expect -

jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:yourdb

You will also need to specify the username and password

As a test try connecting your version of the url, username and password to a database from an SQL client

Comment: Misunderstood. It was only example without real names, but ok I changed it. Just to clarify, connection is established, it works fine, but when it test runs longer (more 1 minute), I got this error

Comment: Are you tearing down connections after each test?

Comment: No, I don't do anything with connections at all. Spring/Hibernate take care about it

Comment: But isnt DBContext creating a new connection each time setup is called, and these are not being torn down?

Comment: Sounds similar to this [problem] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205160/what-can-cause-intermittent-ora-12519-tns-no-appropriate-handler-found-errors)

Comment: I have this problem also if I run only one test alone.