# getting this followed error org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException using Spring batch and Oracle 10g as external library

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Please check the below Client and Configurtaion program..using JdbcCursorItemReader to read the details from Oracle 10g after that printing those details on to console : can able to view the output but below mentioned error am getting :

Pom.xml dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Spring Batch Configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class EappointmentBatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBulderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private BatchItemProcessor batchItemProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private BatchItemWriter batchItemWriter;
    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
    private String sql="select agent_id,agent_name,agent_branch from agent";

    @Bean
    public Job configureEappointmentJob() {
        JobBuilder jobBuilder=jobBulderFactory.get("eappointment_job");
        jobBuilder.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer());
        SimpleJobBuilder eappointmentJob=jobBuilder.start(configureEappointmentStep());
        return eappointmentJob.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step configureEappointmentStep() {
        StepBuilder stepBuilder=stepBuilderFactory.get("eappointment_step");
        SimpleStepBuilder<Agent, Agent> simpleStepBuilder=stepBuilder.chunk(1);
        simpleStepBuilder.reader(configureBatchItemReader());
        simpleStepBuilder.processor(batchItemProcessor);
        simpleStepBuilder.writer(batchItemWriter);
        return simpleStepBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Agent> configureBatchItemReader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Agent> batchItemReader=new JdbcCursorItemReader<Agent>();
        batchItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        batchItemReader.setSql(sql);
        batchItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Agent>(Agent.class));
        return batchItemReader;
    }

}
```

batch Client program :

```
package org.gelm.portal.batch.client;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.gelm.portal.*"})
public class EappointmentBatchClient implements CommandLineRunner{

    private static final Logger clientLogger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(EappointmentBatchClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher batchLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job eAppointmentJob;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EappointmentBatchClient.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    clientLogger.info("Command Line Runner is executing");  
    Map<String,JobParameter> mapParameters=new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
    mapParameters.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters eAppParameters=new JobParameters(mapParameters);
    batchLauncher.run(eAppointmentJob, eAppParameters); 
    }

}
```

After executing this code ,am able to get the details from DB , but along with followed error as below mentioned :

OutPut Console :

```
2019-12-25 12:36:08.509  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.client.EappointmentBatchClient   : Starting EappointmentBatchClient on User with PID 64464 (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DevOps\Spring\STS_Space\EappointmentBatch\target\classes started by HP in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DevOps\Spring\STS_Space\EappointmentBatch)
2019-12-25 12:36:08.511  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.client.EappointmentBatchClient   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-25 12:36:10.038  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2019-12-25 12:36:10.199  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2019-12-25 12:36:10.300  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.client.EappointmentBatchClient   : Started EappointmentBatchClient in 2.056 seconds (JVM running for 2.813)
2019-12-25 12:36:10.301  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always]
2019-12-25 12:36:14.323  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=eappointment_job]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=2, -spring.output.ansi.enabled=always}]
2019-12-25 12:36:15.039  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [eappointment_step]
2019-12-25 12:36:15.779  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.i.processor.BatchItemProcessor   : Processor :GELM01  SURESH KUMAR METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.779  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.batch.item.writer.BatchItemWriter  : Writer :GELM01 SURESH KUMAR METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.794  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.i.processor.BatchItemProcessor   : Processor :GELM02  SOWJANYA METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.794  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.batch.item.writer.BatchItemWriter  : Writer :GELM02 SOWJANYA METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.872  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.i.processor.BatchItemProcessor   : Processor :GELM03  LEELA KRISHNA METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.872  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.batch.item.writer.BatchItemWriter  : Writer :GELM03 LEELA KRISHNA METTA
2019-12-25 12:36:15.887  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.b.i.processor.BatchItemProcessor   : Processor :GELM099 Sachin Tendulkar
2019-12-25 12:36:15.888  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.g.p.batch.item.writer.BatchItemWriter  : Writer :GELM099    Sachin Tendulkar
2019-12-25 12:36:16.018  INFO 64464 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=eappointment_job]] failed unexpectedly and fatally with the following parameters: [{run.id=2, -spring.output.ansi.enabled=always}]

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe
```

Comment: check if your database is up

Comment: Hi Sushil, database is up..checked already..read few blogs , they suggesting me that  use oracle 11g 0r 12c for instead of 10g which is quite old. If any suggestion , please let me know

Comment: your job seems to start correctly and not able to get a connection in the middle of execution. `no appropriate service handler found`: you probably have a connection leak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205160/what-can-cause-intermittent-ora-12519-tns-no-appropriate-handler-found-errors